# Rewriting dispatch method

Tags: php, optimization

Is it possible to rewrite this piece of code any better when it comes to efficiency and/or readability?

```
public function dispatch()
{
    $key = array_search($this->reqUri, $this->routes);

    if ($key !== false) {
        if (isset($this->methods[$key])) {
            if ($this->methods[$key] === $this->reqMethod) {
                call_user_func($this->callables[$key]);

                return;
            } else {
                $this->defaultCallable();

                return;
            }
        }

        call_user_func($this->callables[$key]);

        return;
    }

    $this->defaultCallable();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `array_search` will iterate over every element in `$this->routes`. That's not scalable. It would be better to reorganize `$this->routes` so that you can lookup keys more directly, so that your code will work like this:

```
if (isset($this->routes[$this->reqUri])) {
    $key = $this->routes[$this->reqUri];
    // ...
}
```

In this arrangement, the lookup should be in \$O(1)\$ time or close, even with large number of routes.

---

Do you really need the `!== false` here?

> ```
> if ($key !== false) {
> ```

Can't it be simply:

```
if ($key) {
```

---

In the innermost `if`, since you return in both the `if` and the `else`, you could move the `return` statement outside:

```
if (isset($this->methods[$key])) {
    if ($this->methods[$key] === $this->reqMethod) {
        call_user_func($this->callables[$key]);
    } else {
        $this->defaultCallable();
    }
    return;
}
```

---

In terms of readability, I find it slightly better this way:

```
if ($key) {
    if (isset($this->methods[$key])) {
        if ($this->methods[$key] === $this->reqMethod) {
            call_user_func($this->callables[$key]);
            return;
        }
    } else {
        call_user_func($this->callables[$key]);
        return;
    }
}

$this->defaultCallable();
```

That is, the `$this->defaultCallable()` call appears only once instead of twice, everything else still being the same.